# Error in assigning an array to the other in C

Tags: c, pointers

Consider this code segment:

```
char message[255];
char newMessage[255];
int i;
for (i = 0 ; i < 255 ; i++)
     message[i] = i;
newMessage = message;
```

When I try to do this I get for the last line an error:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[255]’ from type ‘char *
```

Why do I get that if the arrays has the same type? How do I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: newMessage = message; //newMessage is a pointer on the second array, after this line both message and newMessage should point to the same first array.

Comment: @MichBoy If you want an independent copy of the array, either use `memcpy()` or copy the array elements one-by-one.

Comment: @lcfseth the main problem with that is that an array variable is like a pointer whose pointing address you can't change. Hence the error.

Comment: @trutheality Right, but even if you could, this wouldn't get him anywhere :) he would just lose reference to the second array. Consider the same example with pointers. It would still not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to fix this is by declaring `newMessage` as a pointer: `char* newMessage`.

Another is by using `memcpy()` -- or `strncpy()` if `message` is a string -- to copy the contents of `message` into `newMessage`.

Which method is preferable depends on what you then do with `newMessage`.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm allowed to change the type of newMessage in my case. Another way, maybe?

Comment: newMessage is already a pointer. char * newMessage and char newMessage[] are equivalent. The latter create the array in memory.

Comment: @lcfseth: They are not equivalent. See the FAQ: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to assign arrays. You can use `memcpy()` to copy the content of one array to another.

Answer (score 2):

Although the arrays are declared as the same type, as soon as you try to use one it turns into a pointer to its first element, which you therefore can't use to assign to another array.

You can copy an array explicitly using `memcpy` or alternatively in the case when an array is part of a structure then it will get copied as part of the structure.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to loop through each element in `message` and assign the values to `newMessage`.  (Or use `memcpy()` as others have suggested.)

The error is only incidental in the context of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you cant copy an array's content from one array to another in the way you have done above.

`int arr[2]`  this is an array of 2 integers `arr[0]` is the first integer and `arr[1]` is the second integer. But. `arr` is an address (immutable) of the zeroth element of the array.

so when you did `newMessage = message;` you were not copying the elements inside the array rather the address in `message`. which is illegal because an array is a constant pointer to a memory. you cannot change it.

Since its a character array. for copying use `strcpy` or `strncpy` see man pages for the description of the two :)